# Why are the images not sharp?

Tags: flutter, image

I am building a small "MyAnimeList" App in Flutter and I am currently building the Details Page, in which I want to show the "Related Anime".
Because I do not want them to use much space I resize them down (like in the picture) but they are blurry

[image]

My Image Code is:

```dart
class Thumbnail extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  const Thumbnail({
    super.key,
    required this.url,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      child: Image.network(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        url,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        cacheWidth: width?.toInt(),
        cacheHeight: height?.toInt(),
        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
        loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
          if (loadingProgress == null) return child;

          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                  ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                  : null,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```dart
Thumbnail(
  url: e.node.mainPicture.medium,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.10,
),
```

I do not find anything related to this by googling it and tbh, I do not really understand why this happens :(

I appreciate every help!

Comment: Which url are you using ? can you please share me the one thumnail url?

Comment: Hey, here is an example that I use: https://api-cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/1120/109232.jpg